# react-chartjs-2 Как выделить точки на графике и удалить их

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

Всем привет! Не могу решить следующую задачу. У меня есть график, который состоит из точек. Как мне выделить несколько точек и удалить их по нажатию кнопки? Нашел хороший пример, но не знаю как применить это у меня. Вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-selection-points/.

У меня получилось по нажатию на точку ее удалять. Вот код, который у меня есть:

```
const dataSet = {
        labels: timeScale,
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'X',
                data: xCoord,
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                fill: false,
                cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone',
                tension: 0.4
            }
       ]
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div>
    <Line data={dataSet} options={{
                         onClick(event, elements, chart) {                              dataSet.datasets[elements[0].datasetIndex].data.splice(elements[0].index, 1);
                            dataSet.labels.splice(elements[0].index, 1);
                            chart.update();
                        },
                    }}/>
</div>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить данную задачу.